# What is a good persistence design for this entity hierarchy?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I'm new to JPA and trying to work out the design for the following classes. All classes have equals and hashcode overriden, getters and setter and empty constructor.

I have a base class for all entities:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    protected Point loc;
    protected List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The Point class is just the standard x-y holder

```
public class Point {
    private int x, y;
}
```

And the Property class holds a name and an id:

```
public class Property {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

There are 3 classes that inherit from `BaseEntity`. The first one is House. A House can hold a *single* family.

```
public class House extends BaseEntity {
    private Family family;
}

public class Tree extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
}
```

Family will be show soon. The second one is the superclass for all the living entities:

```
public abstract class LivingEntity extends BaseEntity {
    public static enum Status { ALIVE, DECEASED }
    int id;
    Status status;
}
```

which includes

```
public class Family extends LivingEntity {
    private House house;
    private List<Minion> members;
}
```

and

```
public class Member extends LivingEntity {
    private Family family;
    private String name;
}
```

So the hierarchy graph is

```
    BaseEntity
        |
       /|\
      / | \
     /  |  \
House Tree  LivingEntity
                |
               / \
         Family   Member
```

and the composition graph is

```
House <---> Family ---> {Member, Member, Member, ...}
               ^           |       |       |
               |----------------------------
```

in addition to what they inherit.

---

House and Tree are identified by their location (in the equals method) so I think I can use that as the `@Id`. I could give them a specific `id` field but it's redundant.

This means that I need to make Point an entity also with a composite ID from its x and y. I don't know if this will cause the same point to be saved multiple times across the DB. I will have different sets of BaseEntities saved, so if 2 are at the same Point will it duplicate the point entry or refer all to one place?

Family and Member are defined by their id because they can move from house to house. So I want to use `id` in LivingEntity as the `@Id` but I it will cause a conflict with the `@Id` from BaseEntities.

Here are the annotations I have:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    protected Point loc;

    @OneToMany
    protected List<Property> effects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@IdClass(value = PointID.class)
public class Point {
    @Id
    private int x, y;
}

class PointID {
    int x, y;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Property {

    @Id
    protected int id;

    protected String name;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class House extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToOne
    private Family family;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Tree extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
}
```

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class LivingEntity extends BaseEntity {
    public static enum Status { ALIVE, DECEASED }

    @Id
    int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Status status;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Family extends LivingEntity {
    @OneToOne // bidirectional? specify mappedBy?
    private House house;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Minion> members;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Member extends LivingEntity {
    @ManyToOne // bidirectional? specify mappedBy?
    private Family family;

    private String name;
}
```

Except for the conflict of the 2 @MappedSuperclass I don't know if I'm using the annotations correctly and in a smart way. What would be a good design for this case?

Comment: What is `@OneToOne protected String name;` ?! A relation is to another entity. A String is not "another entity". All documentation for the main JPA providers explain this

Comment: @NeilStockton Copy paste mistake. fixed.

Comment: Needs to be broken out a bit more.  As you mention with Point, you need to figure out first if this is an entity, with its own identity, or is just an encapsulation of data of the owning class (an embeddable).  What is most important though are your business rules.  I don't really understand why Tree and Family and 'member' would have the same base class.  People are not rooted, so might be associated to an address, but are not defined by it.

Comment: @Chris Tree, Family and Member have the same base class because they all have a location Point and List<Property> of properties. No need for an address. Point ideally is like a singleton - it is the same for all entries in the database. A point (5,6) is the same as any other point (5,6). Does this answer the question about point?

Comment: It misses the point :). An ID is an immutable field, and I don't think point really is immutable for a family, but I don't know your model.  It sounds like you want only 1 point though, so you need to give it an idenity and have your object model reference it.  Using X,Y as a composite PK makes sense as you only want one point with those coords, but it means duplicating that same information everywhere that references point - when you can get the same behavior by adding unique constraints on those fields.  Does everything in you tree really need loc and properties?

Comment: @Chris Probably i don't understand relational databases well which is why all the difficulty is. All members, the family and the house in the same location share the reference to the same point - there is only one object. I don't want to duplicate that info if by that you mean having multiple points of the same coords in the DB. Everything must have a location and properties yes.

Comment: Why are you shoving so much into your base entity?  It has no purpose I can see, as a Person has little in common (nothing I'd say) with a fixed object like a house.  Unless there is a reason for it, don't do it - give them different roots!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your business reasons (it seems strange to have a an 'alive' or 'deceased' status for an entire family instead of just individual members), but for the example given, it seems more realistic to have something like:

```
BaseFixedObject  -> Point
        |
       /|
      / |
     /  | 
House Tree

LivingEntity  -> many Properties
        |
       /|
      / |
     /  | 
Member  | 
     Family  -> many Members


Property -> many BaseFixedObjects
```

Property would then be mostly a collection of assets on a property - A house with a yard that may have many trees.  I don't know if it would reference the Point, or each tree/house has its own point - it depends on your need.  Or you can do away with Property and have LivingEntity reference BaseFixedObjects directly.

The relationships might be bidirectional, so a property may reference the LivingEntity that it is tied to, which would be a single 'member' or Family.  I'm not sure if joint ownership is required outside of families in this model -
 if it is, a Property might need to allow more than one owner, making it a ManyToMany relationship.

This way, your family (likely) has a house that has a fixed point.  It doesn't need to reference the point itself, as you have access to it through the associated properties.